# Add division to regular expression

Tags: regex

Add division symbol to regular expression

```
^(\+|-)?(\d+)?([.]?\d*)?$
```

Look to add slash symbol like expression accepts `4/5`.

Comment: Given regular expression does allow only numbers and decimals ; want the regular expression which accepts division or slash in a given textbox on browser as well.   For example if answer is 0.8 in text box but it can also be 4/5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an optional expression containing `/` and the regexp that matches a number.

```
^(\+|-)?(\d*)([.]?\d*)?(?:/(\+|-)?(\d*)([.]?\d*)?)?$
```

BTW, `(\d+)?` can be simplified to `(\d*)`.

Comment: `(\d+)?` can not be replaced with `(\d*)` inherently, as they capture different sets. The former requires at least 1 number, whereas the later can capture null.

Comment: But because of greediness, it will always capture the longest possible number. If there's no number at all, they'll both capture an empty string -- one because of `*`, the other because the group is optional.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a regex that is more in line with how a language parser would
parse a integer or non-exponential decimal.

That said, like Barmar said, you can just append an optional slash plus number.

`^(?:([+-]?)(\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?:\s*/\s*([+-]?)(\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+))?)$`

Formatted

```
 ^ 
 (?:
      ( [+-]? )                     # (1), plus/minus sign
      (                             # (2 start), number
           \d+ 
           (?: \. \d* )?
        |  \. \d+ 
      )                             # (2 end)
      (?:                           # Optional division
           \s* 
           /                             # division sign
           \s* 
           ( [+-]? )                     # (3), plus/minus sign
           (                             # (4 start), number
                \d+ 
                (?: \. \d* )?
             |  \. \d+ 
           )                             # (4 end)
      )?
 )
 $
```